# .htaccess url rewriting issue: http to https with exception for a directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently using the following .htaccess code to rewrite:

- http://force-t.fr to https://www.force-t.fr
- http://www.force-t.fr to http://www.force-t.fr

  ```
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.force-t.fr$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.force-t.fr/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule (.*) https://www.force-t.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
  ```

Now, I need to add two exceptions :

1. All url starting with `force-t.fr/iot/` needs to be accessible via http **or** https.
2. **IE8/XP** users needs to access the `www.force-t.fr` website in **http only**
   (SNI is not supported by IE8/XP and my certificat is not working for them.)

I don't know how to do this and spend two hours searching without success.